# Vertical alignment of specific tikz tree nodes to another specific node in another tree level

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, alignment

I am trying to make a tree of semittic languages. In the process I want to vertically align a specific tree node in level 2 to a specific tree node in level 1, as indicated in the figure.

[image]

The figure is obtained by the following code. As you can see, the spacing is currently entered manually by `[right=5em]`, but I want the alignment to be automatic. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6em},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=8em},
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=6em},
    edge from parent fork down,
    align=center
    ]
    \node (topp) {semittiske språk}
        child {node {vestlig}
            child {node {nord-vestlig gruppe}
                child {node {ugarisk}}
                child {node {kanaanittisk/\\fønikisk}}
                child {node {hebraisk}}
                child {node {aramaisk}
                    child {node {vest-aramaisk}}
                    child {node {øst-aramaisk}}
                }
            }
            child {node[right=5em] {sør-vestlig gruppe}
                child {node {etiopisk}}
                child {node {arabisk}}
            }
        }
        child {node {eblaittisk (?)}
        }
        child {node {østlig (akkadisk)}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: It seems I have been to vague in my description. I am trying to get the "sør-vestlig gruppe" node to appear spatially below "østlig (akkadisk)" node (without shifting it in the y-direction, only x-direction) so that the two nodes are aligned in the vertical direction. At the moment I have to manually shift this node using `[right="some distance"]` manually to make them aligned; i want the alignment to be automatic, and not me trying different manual adjustments to do so. I am not trying to change the hierarchical structure, it should remain the same, ie. all the nodes should have the same connections as in my example code.

Comment: Simple answer is don't use the basic TikZ tree methods, but use `forest` instead. See [How to draw language family tree in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/444735) for an example. But I don't understand what you want your tree to look like in the end.  Do you want your 'sør-vestlig gruppe` to be a sister to `vestlig`? That doesn't seem to make much sense, but otherwise I don't know what you mean by making it on the same level as it.

Comment: I will check the forest package, thanks. Please also see my edited post - I believe my intentions are better described now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate `forest` solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    forked edge,
    l sep=10mm,
    fork sep=5mm,
    s sep=5mm
}
[semittiske språk
    [vestlig
        [nord-vestlig gruppe
            [ugarisk]
            [kanaanittisk/\\fønikisk, align=center]
            [hebraisk]
            [aramaisk
                [vest-aramaisk]
                [øst-aramaisk]
            ]
        ]
        [sør-vestlig gruppe, before computing xy={s=s("!uu3")-s("!uu1")}
            [etiopisk]
            [arabisk]
        ]
    ]
    [eblaittisk (?), before drawing tree={x=x("!u")}]
    [østlig (akkadisk)]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your take on the problem. I realize there is some benefit in looking deeper into the forest documentation to understand what is going on here.

Comment: After playing with the different solutions, this seems to be the most elegant and robust solution in my opinion. Marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**
After edited question the problem is more clear. It seems that you after for something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {align = center,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            s sep = 0mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 7mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
            }
%
[semittiske språk
    [vestlig
        [nord-vestlig gruppe, fit=band
            [ugarisk]
            [kanaanittisk/\\fønikisk]
            [hebraisk]
            [aramaisk
                    [vest-aramaisk]
                    [øst-aramaisk]
            ]
        ]
        [\phantom{eblait},no edge] % <--- determined by trial
        [sør-vestlig gruppe,
            [etiopisk]
            [arabisk]
        ]
    ]
    [eblaittisk (?),before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
    [østlig\\ (akkadisk)]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

However, according to my opinion, more appealing and space saving is the following tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {align = center,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 5mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
            }
%
[semittiske språk 
    [vestlig 
        [nord-vestlig gruppe, fit=band
            [ugarisk]
            [kanaanittisk/\\fønikisk]
            [hebraisk]
            [aramaisk
                    [vest-aramaisk]
                    [øst-aramaisk]
            ]
        ]
        [sør-vestlig gruppe
            [etiopisk]
            [arabisk]
        ]
    ]
    [eblaittisk (?),before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
    [østlig (akkadisk)]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have updated my post to better describe what I am attempting to do. Do you think this is possible in `forest`?

Comment: @EirikB, yes it is possible. See edited answer.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you also for the other alternative.

Comment: @EirikB You can also align the nodes on the right and then move the subtrees of the preceding siblings over to keep the compactness. The best option probably depends on the details of your use.

Answer (score 4):

This is based on Zarko's original code. I'm posting it because my method keeps the tree more compact by moving the rest of the tree over. Whether you want this or not is a matter of taste, tree width and paper or display size.

[image: aligned rightmost nodes in tree with preceding subtrees moved right for compactness]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% addaswyd o ateb Zarko: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690062/ i gwestiwn Erik B: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/690058/
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree = {
    align=center,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
  }
  [semittiske språk 
    [vestlig 
        [nord-vestlig gruppe
            [ugarisk]
            [kanaanittisk/\\fønikisk]
            [hebraisk]
            [aramaisk
                    [vest-aramaisk]
                    [øst-aramaisk]
            ]
        ]
        [sør-vestlig gruppe, 
        before drawing tree={
          tempdima/.option=x, 
          x/.option={!name=target}.x, 
          for preceding siblings={
            x+/.process={ORw2+d {{!name=target}.x}{tempdima}{#1-#2}},
          },
          delay={for current and siblings=compute xy}
        }
            [etiopisk]
            [arabisk]
        ]
    ]
    [eblaittisk (?), calign with current]
    [østlig (akkadisk), name=target]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you had following siblings for the node you're trying to align, you would *have* to move those to avoid overlapping.

Comment: Thank you for posting your take on the problem. I definitely need to dig deeper into the forest package documentation!

Comment: @EirikB I'd done it before I saw Zarko had edited the answer, so figured I might as well. Forest's 'argument processor' is very powerful and a bit faster than pgfmath, but I, at least, found it initially baffling. If you do logic, it helps to know it works mostly like reverse Polish notation. I don't know what helps if you do something other than logic, though ;).

Comment: better than my solution (+1). I learned about use of "process"

Comment: @Zarko The argument processor is generally quicker than pgfmath. It doesn't make Forest quick, but it is less slow ;). I'm not convinced my solution is better. It depends what you want.